# No Activity Error on Fragment after FindFragementByTag

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Main Activity with multiple Fragments. And this is how how I switch the fragments

```
  public void openFragment(final Fragment fragment, String title, String tag){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .add(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

I have an INT variable in the Main Activity that I update from each of the Fragment to determine which Fragment was active before an orientation change

```
private int ACTIVE_FRAGMENT = 0;
```

During saved instance on the Activity, I save the INT like so

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(Constants.ACTIVE_EVENT_ID, ACTIVE_FRAGMENT);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And onRestoreInstanceState I go back to the Active Fragment like this

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        ACTIVE_FRAGMENT = savedInstanceState.getInt(Constants.ACTIVE_EVENT_ID);
        if (ACTIVE_FRAGMENT > 0){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch (ACTIVE_FRAGMENT) {
                case 1:
                    EventSetupFragmentOne fragmentOne = (EventSetupFragmentOne) fm.findFragmentByTag(Constants.SETUP_FRAGMENT_ONE_TAG);
                    if (fragmentOne != null) {
                        openFragment(fragmentOne, getString(R.string.event_setup_title_1), Constants.SETUP_FRAGMENT_ONE_TAG);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This goes back to the Active Fragment but then throws a No Actitiy found exception

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1125)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
```

What can I do differently to go back to an Active Fragment after a configuration change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `openFragment` on configuration changes.
Fragments will be recreated by the framework.

That's why in `onCreate` method you don't (re)initialize your Fragments if `savedInstanceState == null`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I have 8 Fragments and I need to tell which one to re-create?

Comment: if configuration change is screen rotation, then you don't have to!